# Google tasks position error

Tags: javascript, api, task

I am trying to use the google tasks api in a chrome extension, 
but when I try too make a task with `?previous` set I get this:

```
"{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
"
```

This is the url I am using: `'https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/@default/tasks?previous='+lastid`. I use javascript as my main language.
I am willing to give code samples but only if necessary.

Comment: You should be willing to give code samples only if the answer being given is necessary.

Comment: OK. But that does not help me with my problem.

Comment: Are your credentials correct?

Comment: Anyone here? I am stuck until I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `oauth.sendSignedRequest` like in the official [google tasks api chrome extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-tasks-chrome-extension/source/browse/trunk/tasksapi.js#60), you should be able to add the `previous` argument in `req['parameters']`.